# How to read csv file in Google Cloud Platform jupyter notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I am working on Jupyter notebook in google cloud platform AI notebook. Now I want to read .csv file in GCP which is stored locally in my laptop.

*My approach:*

`df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Desktop\New Folder\Data.csv")`

But its not working. How to read local file in GCP AI notebbok.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this, but here you have three alternatives:

**a) Upload the file from the Jupyter UI:**

1.Open the Jupyter UI.

2.In the left pane of the screen, at the top, below the menus, click the `"Upload files"` button.

3.Select the file from your local file system and click Open.

4.Once the file is available in the left pane of the screen, right-click the file and select `"Copy Path"`.

5.In your Notebook, type the following code, replacing `test.csv` with the path you just copied:

```
import pandas as pd    
df2 = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print(df2)
```

**b. Upload the file to the Notebooks instance's file system**

1.Go to the [Compute Engine screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) in the GCP console.

2.SSH to your AI Platform Notebooks instance, using the `SSH` button.

3.In the new terminal window, click the gear icon and the `"Upload File"` option

4.Select the file from your local file system and click Open.

5.The file will be stored in $HOME/, optionally move it to the desired path.

6.In your Notebook, type the following code, replacing the path accordingly:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to_file/test.csv")
print(df2)
```

**c)Store the file in a GCS bucket.**

1.[Upload your file to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects).

2.In your Notebook, type the following code, replacing the bucket and file names accordingly:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage
from io import BytesIO
client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = "your-bucket"
file_name = "your_file.csv"
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.get_blob(file_name)
content = blob.download_as_string()
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(content))
print(df)
```