# Read vertex ai datasets in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to create a python utility that will take dataset from vertex ai datasets and will generate statistics for that dataset. But I am unable to check the dataset using jupyter notebook. Is there any way out for this?

Comment: So you want to call VertexAI dataset from Jupyther Notebooks. What is that dataset, its text one? What statistics would you like to get? Number of words? Please elaborate it.

Comment: Yes I want to get statistics for text and tabular data both. Stats like std_dev, count based features for tabular data and for text data length of sentences, words count, char count. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Onlyt things comes to my minds are [Vertex Pipelines: Metrics visualization and run comparison using the KFP SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/master/notebooks/official/pipelines/metrics_viz_run_compare_kfp.ipynb) and [Vertex Pipelines: model train, upload, and deploy using google-cloud-pipeline-components](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/master/notebooks/official/pipelines/google_cloud_pipeline_components_model_train_upload_deploy.ipynb) but not sure if that is what you are asking. Some scenario/use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use [Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai) dataset inside `Jupyter Notebook`. I don't think that this is currently possible. You are able to export `Vertex AI` datasets to `Google Cloud Storage` in JSONL format:

> Your dataset will be exported as a list of text items in JSONL format. Each row contains a Cloud Storage path, any label(s) assigned to that item, and a flag that indicates whether that item is in the training, validation, or test set.

At this moment, you can use `BigQuery` data inside `Notebook` using `%%bigquery` like it's mentioned in [Visualizing BigQuery data in a Jupyter notebook.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter) or use `csv_read()` from machine directory or `GCS` like it's showed in the [How to read csv file in Google Cloud Platform jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956470/) thread.

However, you can fill a `Feature Request` in [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) to add the possibility to use `VertexAI` dataset directly in the `Jupyter Notebook` which will be considered by the `Google Vertex AI Team`.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, are you trying to access vertex ai dataset which is in you gcp project into the jupyter notebook ? If so, try below code and see if you can access dataset.

```
def list_datasets(project_id, compute_region, filter=None):
"""List all datasets."""
result = []
# [START automl_tables_list_datasets]
# TODO(developer): Uncomment and set the following variables
# project_id = 'PROJECT_ID_HERE'
# compute_region = 'COMPUTE_REGION_HERE'
# filter = 'filter expression here'

from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl

client = automl.TablesClient(project=project_id, region=compute_region)
print('client:',client)
# List all the datasets available in the region by applying filter.
response = client.list_datasets(filter=filter)

print("List of datasets:")
for dataset in response:
    # Display the dataset information.
    print("Dataset name: {}".format(dataset.name))
    print("Dataset id: {}".format(dataset.name.split("/")[-1]))
    print("Dataset display name: {}".format(dataset.display_name))
    metadata = dataset.tables_dataset_metadata
    print(
        "Dataset primary table spec id: {}".format(
            metadata.primary_table_spec_id
        )
    )
    print(
        "Dataset target column spec id: {}".format(
            metadata.target_column_spec_id
        )
    )
    print(
        "Dataset target column spec id: {}".format(
            metadata.target_column_spec_id
        )
    )
    print(
        "Dataset weight column spec id: {}".format(
            metadata.weight_column_spec_id
        )
    )
    print(
        "Dataset ml use column spec id: {}".format(
            metadata.ml_use_column_spec_id
        )
    )
    print("Dataset example count: {}".format(dataset.example_count))
    print("Dataset create time: {}".format(dataset.create_time))
    print("\n")

    # [END automl_tables_list_datasets]
    result.append(dataset)

return result
```

you require to pass project_id and comupte_region while calling this function.